# Qt Creator predefined macro file

Tags: qt, macros, qt-creator

Our project has a predefined macro file that is given to the compiler (GCC/Clang) with the `-imacros` flag. It contains the platform specific macros so it is a complicated and long file. Can I specify a predefined macro file in Qt creator because without it the code completion fails? I know that I can specify my macros in the `DEFINES` section of the .pro file but we have them in a standalone file. It is not possible to move them into the .pro file because other colleagues use Eclipse.

Comment: why not including it?

Comment: It was a design decision. The compiler supports the -imacros flag so we decided to use it. It is common and for instance Eclipse supports it: [link](http://imgur.com/a/AVFMO)

Answer (score 1):

You can add `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` to your pro file.

It specifies the C++ compiler flags for building a project.
Something like this:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -imacros <file_with_macros>
```

I hope it help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however unfortunately it has no effect on code completion :( We use it already.

Comment: It won't have an effect on code completion, and you didn't ask about it anyway. You asked how to pass relevant option to the compiler. This answer covers that. Code completion is a separate story and you need to ask a new question about it. Make sure that you delete the build folder to see the effect of this option.

Comment: @KubaOber The question is: "Can I specify a predefined macro file in Qt creator because without it the **code completion fails**?" Before you had modified the title it was Qt Creator predefined macro file because I would like to inform the Qt creator and **not** the compiler about the predefined macro file.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Sorry that I missed it.